# Get the value of a input with jQuery inside an $each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an $each that nicely collects a jQuery wrapped set of inputs.  I want to iterate through them and get their value.  When I console log $(this), it shows me the selected input correctly, but putting .val() after it says undefined.  Help?

```
        var currentMACBindings = $("div[class*='mac-row-']");

        $.each( currentMACBindings, function( key, value ) {
            console.log("key is ", key);
            console.log("value is ", $(this));        // this works
            console.log("value is ", $(this).val());  // this no workie
        });
```

Comment: Also put your `html` in your question to get better understanding of the question. How will one execute this code ?

Comment: `<div />`s have no `value`. You probably want [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead

Comment: OOOHHHH Yes, I meant to select the ID.  THANKS!!  Sorry

Comment: Then you should use `.attr('id')`

Comment: @Sergio, why the id?

Comment: @Sergio Keep it simple: `this.id` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your divs have a value attribute:

```
    $("div[class*='mac-row-']").each(function( idx, element ) {
        console.log("key is ", idx);
        console.log("value is ", $(element).attr('value') );
    });
```

Else, if it's inputs:

```
    var currentMACBindings = $("input").each(function( idx, element ) {
        console.log("index is ", idx);
        console.log("value is ", $(element).val() ); 
    });
```

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ : The `$.each()` function is not the same as `$(selector).each()`, which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are selecting Div's. Div's does not have a `val()` method. `val()` method is for getting value of input fields like textbox,checkboxes etc.. 
You should find the inputs inside of your selected div and then call `val()`

This should work.

```
 var currentMACBindings = $("div[class*='mac-row-']").find("input");
 $.each( currentMACBindings, function( key, value ) {

      console.log("value is ", $(this).val());  
 });
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/qijufu/edit?js,console,output) is a working sample.

If you are trying to get the content of non input fields like div's/span, you should consider `text()` or `html()` methods. Be careful. these method gives the content of nested childs as well. So use carefully.

Or if you are trying to get some other attribute of the div, you may consider using the `attr()` method.

```
 var currentMACBindings = $("div[class*='mac-row-']");
 $.each( currentMACBindings, function( key, value ) {

      console.log("id of div is ", $(this).attr("id"));  
 });
```